# IE9 browser cache issue

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer-9

I am facing a browser cache issue for IE9. I tried to clear cache using below mentioned ways.
Included the below code in the jsp page:

```
<% response.setHeader("pragma","no-cache");//HTTP 1.1 
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); 
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
response.addDateHeader("Expires", -1); 
response.setDateHeader("max-age", 0); 
//response.setIntHeader ("Expires", -1); 
//prevents caching at the proxy server 
response.addHeader("cache-Control", "private"); %>
```

Comment: Since cleaning the cache is not working, are you totally sure that you have a *cache* problem? Couldn't it be something else?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that getting IE to cooperate usually requires:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```